# Can be make trigger fire only once for mutiple insert in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to send a mail for insert in table . I have multiple insert in may .pdc .

Can we do that ?

I tried inserting multiple record at once .

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES ('Billy', 125, 'London Office')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

But it still fire the trigger 3 time.

The trigger i have written is this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema."my_trigger"
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON myschema.mytable
 begin
   ----- email notification here
 END;
```

Thanks.

And i write .pdc , in which i write multiple insert for table when i execute it . It trigger many time as DML happen muliple time.

I have read many block i did not find any such answer.

Can we make it to fire only once?

**EDIT**

FOR UPDATE

```
update mytable  set column2 = 123 where column1=  'first';
update mytable  set column2 = 124 where column1=  'second';
update mytable  set column2 = 125 where column1=  'first';
commit;
```

How can we do the same for update?
Thanks

Comment: Added `insert all`

Comment: Could't you at the end of your inserts - insert also another value to a dummy table which will have the desired trigger?

Comment: @Plirkee - How will inserting into a dummy table fire a trigger on the target table?

Comment: @APC what I meant was, if it is a script that the OP is running then the trigger could go into a dummy table not the target table. And the dummy table could be updated only once per run - thus executing the trigger also once.

Comment: @Plirkee - Aren't triggers bad enough already without building them on dummy tables instead of the actual table they relate to? Anyway, the correct solution is fix the INSERT statement not the infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that INSERT ALL executes each branch as a separate statement. So this ...

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('Billy', 125, 'London Office')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

... is actually three INSERT statements, hence your statement-level trigger fires three times.

If you want to insert multiple rows in a single statement you need to use INSERT INTO ... SELECT syntax, like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3)
select 'John', 123, 'Lloyds Office' from dual
union all 
select 'Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office' from dual
union all 
select 'Billy', 125, 'London Office' from dual
;
```

This example uses the Oracle dummy table DUAL to generate one row and the UNION ALL operator to join multiple SELECT statements into a single result set.

Comment: can you tell how the below statement works . Please can you describe it or can give the link. Also is there is any performance difference in running both?